# Get specific changeset after multiple check-ins in TFS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, tfs

Problem is we had done some changes and check in the code and build was created successfully,
two other team members checked in code which contained lot of files and the build started failing. Now I have to roll back the changes to my checkin(till it build was successful) state.

Please let me know if there is an alternative to manually roll back each file and check in.
I can do Get Specfic Version>Changesetno. but it will successfully create my local build. I want that to happen in TFS in one go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's like Roland says. Moreover, having installed the [latest](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) TFS Powertools you get the additional option to graphically make your choices:
[image]

So you only need to know which changesets you want to rollback.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a rollback if you have the [Team Foundation Powertoys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963). It's not a rollback in the SourceSafe sense that destroyed later check-ins, but more a "perform all the required edits to undo the subsequent check-ins" approach.